# Pandas - How do I check three values per row in one data frame against each row in another data frame with conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames, 1 which contains sales data and the other which contains refund data.  I want to check the refund data to see if a sale has taken place prior with some conditions in place and add a marker in a new column to say whether it is true or false.

Condition 1 - The Product ID matches in both data frames
Condition 2 - The unit quantity matches in both data frames
Condition 2 - The Refund date is after the sale date
Condition 4 - The Refund is within 28 days of the sale date

Edit: Data frames added with reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd

refunds = {'Article_ID': [30134243, 10234145, 93485321, 56543456, 34581234],
           'Txn': ['Return', 'Return', 'Return', 'Return', 'Return'],
           'Description': ['DVD', 'CD', 'Vinyl', 'DVD', 'CD'],
           'Quantity': [2, 1, 1, 3, 2],
           'Refund Date': ['30/01/2023', '02/02/2023', '05/02/2023', '15/02/2023', '01/03/2023'],
           'Refund Date - 28 Days': ['02/01/2023', '05/01/2023', '05/01/2023', '18/01/2023', '01/02/2023']}
dfRefunds = pd.DataFrame(data=refunds)

sales = {'Article_ID': [93485321, 10234145, 30134243, 56543456, 34581234],
           'Txn': ['Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale'],
           'Description': ['Vinyl', 'CD', 'DVD', 'DVD', 'CD'],
           'Quantity': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
           'Sale Date': ['07/01/2023', '08/01/2023', '10/01/2023', '20/02/2023', '27/02/2023']}

dfSales = pd.DataFrame(data=sales)
```

I have tried the following using iteration but the data frames can be 6000 rows which is very slow.

```
for idx, row in dfRedunds.iterrows():

        for idx2, row2 in dfSales.iterrows():

            if int(row2['Article_ID']) == int(row['Article_ID']) & int(row2['Quantity']) ==     int(row['Quantity']) & int(row2['Sale Date']) <= row['Refund Date'] & row2['Sale Date'] >= row['Refund Date - 28 days']:
           
                  row['Status'] = 'Sale Found'
            
             else:
                  row['Status'] = 'No Match'
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

The expected output of dfRefund should be :

```
Article_ID      Txn       Description     Quantity    Refund Date     Refund Date - 28 Days    Status
30134243        Return    DVD             2           30/01/2023      02/01/2023               Sale Found     
10234145        Return    CD              1           02/02/2023      05/01/2023               Sale Found
93485321        Return    Vinyl           1           05/02/2023      08/01/2023               No Match
56543456        Return    DVD             3           15/02/2023      18/01/2023               No Match
34581234        Return    CD              2           01/03/2023      01/02/2023               Sale Found
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please edit the question and add minimal reproducible example: with both dataframes

Comment: Apologies, I have amended with reproducible code for both dataframes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather try merging these tables first and then fill in by filter like this:

```
# you put your merged table in t. importance is in using left merge 
t = refund.merge(sale, how = 'left', on=['Article_ID', 'Quantity', 'Description'])

# by appling <<lambda x ..., axis=1>> you walk through all rows and check your conditions
t['Status'] = t.apply(lambda x: 'Sale Found' if pd.to_datetime(x['SaleDate'], dayfirst=True)>=pd.to_datetime(x['RefundDate-28Days'], dayfirst=True) and pd.to_datetime(x['SaleDate'], dayfirst=True)<pd.to_datetime(x['RefundDate'], dayfirst=True) else 'No Match', axis=1)

# this one will give you needed view
t = t.drop(columns = ['Txn_y', 'SaleDate']).rename(columns = {'Txn_x': 'Txn'})
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POBRt.png)

Note: I added condition on matching Description

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use the apply function.
Here is a first idea of how you can use it :

```
def toto(row, dfSales):
    saleRow = dfSales[row.index]
    if ***YOUR CONDITIONS WITH ROW (refunds) and SALEROW (sales)***:
        return "Sale Found"
    else:
        return "No Match"

dfRefunds['Status'] = dfRefunds.apply(lambda x: toto(x, dfSales), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I am very much a beginner with Python but I have attempted to implement you suggested solution.  I have come across an indexing error which I am unsure of.

KeyError: "['Refund Date', 'Refund Date - 28 Days'] not in index"

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas `merge` you can join both dataframes on defined columns. Then I would calculate the difference between both dates (first you have to convert the columns to datetime) and use the `map_condition` function to fill the `Status` column using panda's `map` function.

```py
import pandas as pd

refunds_data = {'Article_ID': [30134243, 10234145, 93485321, 56543456, 34581234],
           'Txn': ['Return', 'Return', 'Return', 'Return', 'Return'],
           'Description': ['DVD', 'CD', 'Vinyl', 'DVD', 'CD'],
           'Quantity': [2, 1, 1, 3, 2],
           'Refund Date': ['30/01/2023', '02/02/2023', '05/02/2023', '15/02/2023', '01/03/2023'],
           'Refund Date - 28 Days': ['02/01/2023', '05/01/2023', '05/01/2023', '18/01/2023', '01/02/2023']}
refunds = pd.DataFrame(data=refunds_data)

sales_data = {'Article_ID': [93485321, 10234145, 30134243, 56543456, 34581234],
           'Txn': ['Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale'],
           'Description': ['Vinyl', 'CD', 'DVD', 'DVD', 'CD'],
           'Quantity': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
           'Sale Date': ['07/01/2023', '08/01/2023', '10/01/2023', '20/02/2023', '27/02/2023']}

sales = pd.DataFrame(data=sales_data)

merged = refunds.merge(sales, on=["Article_ID", "Quantity"], how="left")
merged["Refund Date"] = pd.to_datetime(merged["Refund Date"], dayfirst=True)
merged["Sale Date"] = pd.to_datetime(merged["Sale Date"], dayfirst=True)
merged["difference"] = merged["Refund Date"] - merged["Sale Date"]


def map_condition(difference):
    if difference.days <= 28:
        return "Sale Found"
    return "No Match"

merged["Status"] = merged["difference"].map(map_condition)
print(merged.to_string())

>>>     Article_ID   Txn_x Description_x  Quantity Refund Date Refund Date - 28 Days Txn_y Description_y  Sale Date difference      Status
>>>  0    30134243  Return           DVD         2  2023-01-30            02/01/2023  Sale           DVD 2023-01-10    20 days  Sale Found
>>>  1    10234145  Return            CD         1  2023-02-02            05/01/2023  Sale            CD 2023-01-08    25 days  Sale Found
>>>  2    93485321  Return         Vinyl         1  2023-02-05            05/01/2023  Sale         Vinyl 2023-01-07    29 days    No Match
>>>  3    56543456  Return           DVD         3  2023-02-15            18/01/2023   NaN           NaN        NaT        NaT    No Match
>>>  4    34581234  Return            CD         2  2023-03-01            01/02/2023  Sale            CD 2023-02-27     2 days  Sale Found
```

Possibly you could check if `Refund Date - 28 Days` < `Sale`. But in your data there is a wrong `Refund Date - 28 Days` date for the `Vinyl` row: it should be `08/01/2023` instead of `05/01/2023`.